# How are Bundles transfered in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, bundle, data-transfer

```
       onCreate(Bundle)
       onCreateView(.., .., Bundle)
       onActivityCreated(Bundle)
       onRestoreState(Bundle)
```

what did these Bundles come from?
Another Question:

```
//In SubActivity(created by MainActivity)
Fragment frg = ....;
frg.setArguements(getIntent().getExtras());
```

We know by calling `setArguements()` on a `Fragment object` equals to giving it a Bundle. The problem is, is this the bundle passed to `onCreateView()` and `onActivityCreated()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what did these Bundles come from?

Those are copies of the `Bundle` supplied to `onSaveInstanceState()` of a previous edition of this fragment.

> We know by calling setArguements() on a Fragment object equals to giving it a Bundle. The problem is, is this the bundle passed to onCreateView() and onActivityCreated() ?

No. Use `getArguments()` to retrieve a copy of the `Bundle` attached via `setArguments()`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: I am uncertain what you are referring to. The second quoted passage was in reference to `setArguments()`. I added more to the quote to make that clearer.

Comment: You're right, my reading comprehension is out of place. Sorry!